# What does the "at" operator do in C++? For example, string.at or word.at

Tags: c++, function, operators

```
// Iterate(loop/repetition) over the word
for(int i = 0; i < (int)word.size(); i++ ){
    // Get a character
    char ch = word.at(i);

    // If the character matches the character we're looking for
    if(searchCh == ch){

        // Increment a counter
        counter++; // counter = counter + 1
```

What does word.at(i) mean in the operator or what does the "at" operator do in C++? For example, string.at or word.at

Comment: read this: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/at

Comment: It is not an operator. And it is easy enough to look it up.

Comment: Okay thanks everyone. I just googled it and understood it clearly. It wasn't popping up on google because I thought it was an operator.

Comment: Why not just test it like: "if (searchChar==word[i])" ? and change the conditional expression to "i<word.length()"

Comment: @Donald Saving values in local variables is a very common practice, making debugging easy, especially in complex DS, where you may need to see `this->data->registered_entries[n].data.name.c_str()`.

Comment: It's almost like documentation doesn't exist.

Comment: @Barmar: Please do not answer questions in the comment section.

Answer (score 3):

You probably mean "how is `word.at(i)` different from `word[i]`"?

`word.at(i)` generally checks whether `i` is in range and throws an exception if not.  `word[i]` just is undefined behaviour if `i` is out of range.

Also, with `word[word.size()]` you can access the implicit trailing `'\0'`-byte, but for `word.at(word.size())` the index is out of range.

Answer (score 1):

`at()` is a member function in C++.
`s.at()` returns the letter at position `i` in the string. But if the position is 
not in the range, it throws an exception.